# Changing option for grunt jshint

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, jshint

I have a web app created by `yeoman` webapp generator, that has this structure:

```
myApp
    app
    node_modules
        grunt
        grunt-contrib-jshint
    test
```

I try to change the `quotmark: "single"` option for `jshint` to `quotmark: true` to turn off the error for double quote. I try to set it in:

- myApp/.jshintrc
- myApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/.jshintrc

However, it seems that my change is not registered when I run grunt:
`grunt jshint`

Do I have to make that change anywhere else?

Comment: Just double checking that `quotmark` is `"quotmark"` in your .jshintrc file?

Comment: Yes, `"quotmark"` in both of my .jshintrc are as you suggest.

Comment: First, never touch anything in node_modules. In fact, set your editor and whatever else to not search/list that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem I am having. I was having this:

```
var myVar = [
  {
    "name": "a name"   //  jshint warning: Mixed double and single quotes.
  }
];
```

The correct option I should set is `"quotmark": false` instead of `"quotmark": true` to turn off the quote mark checking, even though I don't see why it should be an issue in my case.

The `.jshintrc` file to set this option is: `myApp/.jshintrc`

Thanks everyone for your help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 6):

How does your Gruntfile look like? You should have something like

```
jshint: {
    options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc' // relative to Gruntfile
    }
}
```

Comment: I have multiples Gruntfile.js: `myApp/Gruntfile.js`,  `myApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/Gruntfile.js`...All of them have the `jshint` in `grunt.initConfig` just like you mention.

Comment: do they contain the reference to `jshintrc`? that's what you need

Comment: Thanks. Yes, they all have the reference to the `.jshintrc` , which is placed in the same folder as the Gruntfile.js. I try to modify the `.jshintrc` but that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First, never touch anything in node_modules. In fact, set your editor and whatever else to not search/list that folder.

Second, you should look at the valid options for jshint: http://jshint.com/docs/options/#quotmark

Third, edit your .myApp/.jshintrc file with the valid option you want. Pick single or double quotes and stick with that throughout your project. Thats why it complains.